# margin notes disturb line numbering of listings

Tags: listings, marginnote

I've tried to add margin notes for listings (PS: footnotes work fine), but when line numbering is on, the margin notes disturb the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C++,numbers=left,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;(*@\marginnote{margin note}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}

%% I've tried to wrap \marginnote with boxes, but could't fix it.

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;(*@\vbox{\marginnote{margin note}}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It the package `marginnote` is not obligatory, `\marginpar` does the work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C++,numbers=left,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 cout << i << endl;(*@\marginpar{margin note}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}

%% I've tried to wrap \marginnote with boxes, but could't fix it.

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
cout << i << endl;(*@\marginpar{margin note}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]